# Laravel ckeditor data doesn't insert in database

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, ckeditor

I am using Laravel 5.2 and using UniSharp/laravel-ckeditor package to implement ckeditor in my project.Everything seems to work fine.But when I send data of ckeditor input field,it's not inserting in database.The data of other input field working fine.When i use normal text-area instead of ckeditor it's also working fine.

The Form In my view:

```
 {{Form::open(array('url'=>'gettopics'))}}
            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control"/>
           **<input type="textarea" name="detail" id="article-ckeditor">**
    {{Form::close()}}



<script>
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'article-ckeditor' );

    </script>
```

The Route:

```
Route::post('gettopics','TopicsController@gettopics');
```

The Controller:

```
public function gettopics(Request $request){
    $topic=new Topic;
$topic->title=$request->Input('title');
$topic->detail=$request->Input('detail');
 $topic->save();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Textarea as HTML tag is inserted incorrectly. You should change your code as follows:

```
My Editor:<br>
            <textarea name="article-ckeditor" id="article-ckeditor">&lt;p&gt;Initial editor content.&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
            <script>
                CKEDITOR.replace( 'article-ckeditor' );
            </script>
```

Also in your controller, there is no function called Input, it's input. Change your controller as follows:

```
public function gettopics(Request $request){
    $topic=new Topic;
    $topic->title=$request->input('title');
    $topic->detail=$request->input('detail');
    $topic->save();
}
```

Comment: Now It's working.Thank You!!!.But How can i show the data in my page.Normal Procedure isn't working.

Comment: what do you mean by normal procedure? `{{ $topic->detail }}`?

Comment: Yeah.When I use {{ $topic->detail }},it's acting weird.                            <blockquote> <p><big>I told the family I needed time off to think for myself. The view is great up here, but I've seen it so many times after a while you get used to it. After a while the extraordinary loses its 'extra'.</big></p> </blockquote>

Comment: Sure, you need to escape it. Use {!! $topic->detail !!}

Answer (score 3):

To render the html content, do this

```
{{!! $topic->detail !!}}
```

Note that if spaced wrongly, it will not work. So, make sure there is no space **before** the first '!!' and no space **after** the last '!!'.